# DropDownListFor Razor with List<string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", new { profil = Model.SelectedProfil }, FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProfil, new SelectList(Model.Profils.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),"Value","Text"))
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
}
```

Profils = List of string

SelectedProfil = string

SelectedProfil is always null to the controller on post

Comment: Have you added a custom route for that post action in the routes file? I say that because the route you're using through the helper (Html.BeginForm("Add", "TestController", new { profil = Model.SelectedProfil }) differs from the -usually- default generated one since the parameter passed is always named "id", while here its called "profil". Just an idea, but with my default route configuration I have to add a custom route so that such post action could work..

Comment: Originally  using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", new { bd = Model.BD, appName = Model.SelectedAppName, profil = Model.SelectedProfil }, FormMethod.Post)) Everything work except profil parameter is always null

Comment: Its normal you have to add custom route because TestController shoud be named Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", FormMethod.Post))

@Html.DropDownList("profil", new SelectList(Model.Profils.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),"Value","Text")))

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(string profil)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary to revert to the weak typed method. Use `DropDownListFor()` as per your question, remove `new { profil = Model.SelectedProfil }` and the method should be `public ActionResult Add(string SelectedProfil)`